# Build existing code in Visual Studio code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I am trying to build code in visual studio code which is written in Visual Studio 2015 and facing the following error even though I am using .net framework version 4.5.2.

Error as follows :

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.302\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1179,5):
>   error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" were not found. To resolve this,
>   install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or
>   retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you
>   have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be
>   resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in
>   place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be
>   correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
>   [D:\For_Team_AC\Documents\EngineTester\EngineTester.csproj]

Comment: Did you (re-)install the SDK itself and the targetting pack as mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Did you read the error message? It says .NET 4.5.2 SDK or targetting pack isn't installed, you need to install it.

Comment: Well did you _install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed_?

Comment: SDK is installed but what is targetting pack?